# How to import private key from a certificate to a keystore (Tomcat)?

Tags: java, security, tomcat, ssl, jira

After installing JIRA (Tomcat server) we've noticed we have security issues (clear password). So we decided to implement SSL.

We decided to follow steps based on these two tutorials :

- [Running JIRA over SSL or HTTPS](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Running+JIRA+over+SSL+or+HTTPS)
- [Apache Tomcat 7, SSL Configuration HOW-TO](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html)

We are using:

- A certificate generate by a Certificate Authority.
- Tomcat 7
- Windows server 2008 R2

Our steps:

- Import the certificate (with the `keytool` command, the all chain)
- Add Java argument (`-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=` and `Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword`)
- Change `server.xml` file (remove the comments and edit the SSL part)
- Restart Tomcat service (and the server)

Results:

- SSL is not working
- We can see *trustedCertEntry* and *PrivateKeyEntry* in personal store of windows

After investigation we think the issue is that the entry in our keystore are *trustedCertEntry* and there is no *PrivateKeyEntry*.

Do we need to import *PrivateKeyEntry* into the Tomcat keystore? If yes, how we can import *PrivateKeyEntry* into a keystore?

Comment: How did you import your certificate, and where did you store your private key in the first place?

Comment: Without specific config entries to show, the only thing that springs out is that an entry in the `trustStore` only allows you to trust other (e.g. self-cert) certificates, but doesn't actually add the key into the `keystore`.

Comment: @Bruno : to import the certificate we used keytool -import -alias tomcatCACert -file JIRA.CNPPD.LAB.cer -keystore "c:\users\test\cacerts.keystore" with the command line keytool -list -v -keystore "c:\users\test\cacerts.keystore" we can see our 3 certificates.

Comment: OK, so that's just the cert. Where did you generate your private key (before or during the cert application process)?

Comment: @Bruno : It's seems we didn't generate the private keys yet. I suppose we have to use  the command _%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool -genkey -alias tomcat -keyalg RSA_ right ? what we have to do after ? import it in the keystore ?

Comment: You *must* have generated the private key (and the public key) before getting this certificate. Generating a new key pair now would mean that you would need to get your certificate re-issued.

Comment: Hi @bruno : When we generated the corporate certificate it generated a private key which we see in the windows key store (using the certificates MMC). Now that we added the trusted certificate chain into the tomcat keystore, is there a process to insert the private key into that keystore as well ? If not, how does the keystore know about the private key ?